# .htaccess rediret from 3th level domains to WordPress page and keep the url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a bunch of 3th level domains and I need to redirect them to different  wordpress page.
I did it with this code in the .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} third\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/subs-page/ [R=301,L]
```

and it works, but I need to keep the original url in the address bar. Is that possible?

Comment: your 301, redirect will cause i to redirect every time.

Answer (score 1):

If these subdomains are folders in the root, you can try this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} third\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subs-page/$1 [L]
```

Or you can use a Proxy pass using the `P` flag to keep the URL in the browser. Make sure mod_proxy is enabled.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} third\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/subs-page/$1 [P]
```

Comment: they aren't folder. they are pages of wordpress, the files or directory doesn't exist on the filesystem, they are provided dynamically form the database. I think I don't have mod_proxy enabled. I will ask to my ISP

Comment: Then proxy might be your best bet.

Comment: What about security with mod_proxy?

Comment: What about it? mod_proxy is used all the time. I'm not sure what security you're talking about. All it's doing is passing the request to your main domain on the same server. For instance, Apache and Tomcat uses mod_proxy because that's how the requests get to Tomcat server. It's a very common setup.

Comment: I have big problems with this. I try with yuour htaccess but when I did I see a lot of error about cross domain security. I added the third.domain.com to the apache aliases and tryed to add a virtual host on the same documentroot of the main domain without result. This is the error:

Font from origin 'http://www.domain.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://third.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.

How to fix this?